# Origin of strange formula for equilibrium standard deviation

Tags: regression, probability, variance, stochastic-processes

In the paper

> M. Avellaneda and J. H. Lee, [Statistical arbitrage in the U.S. equities market](http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/avellane/AvellanedaLeeStatArb071108.pdf), July 2008,

in the Appendix on page 46, how does he get equilibrium standard deviation as following:

$$\sigma_{eq} = \sqrt{\frac{\text{Variance}(\zeta)}{1 − b^2}}$$

If anyone knows the paper, please explain.

Much appreciated,

Comment: I posted another question on the same paper - http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9396/why-are-cumulative-residuals-from-regression-on-stock-and-index-returns-mean-reve. Please look at it if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The authors are providing a simple means for estimating the parameters of a mean-reverting Orstein-Uhlenbeck process via a regression on returns at discretized points in time.

The model they are considering has a representation as a stochastic differential equation of the form [pg. 16, Eq. (12)]
$$
\newcommand{\rd}{\mathrm{d}}
\rd X(t) = \kappa (m - X(t)) \rd t + \sigma \rd W(t)
$$
where $W(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion.

The solution to this SDE is well-known and easy to find via Ito's lemma and an analogous technique to integrating constants in ODEs. The solution is [pg. 17, Eq. (13)]
$$
X(t_0 + \Delta t) = e^{-\kappa \Delta t} X(t_0) + (1-e^{-\kappa \Delta t}) m + \sigma \int_{t_0}^{\,t_0 + \Delta t} e^{-\kappa(t_0+\Delta t - s)} \, \rd W(s) .
$$

This is a Gaussian process and so is characterized by its mean and covariance as a function of time. Letting "time go to infinity" (i.e., $\Delta t \to \infty$), we get an equilibrium mean and variance of
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E} X(t) &= m \\
\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}(X(t)) &= \frac{\sigma^2}{2 \kappa}
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, skipping to the appendix [bottom of page 45], the authors are trying to estimate the parameters by doing a regression using the discrete values of the process and model
$$
X_{n+1} = a + b X_n + \zeta_{n+1} .
$$

Matching up the parameters $a$ and $b$ with the portions from above, we get that
$$
\begin{aligned}
a &= m (1 - e^{-\kappa \Delta t}) \\
b &= e^{-\kappa \Delta t} \\
\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}(\zeta) &= \sigma^2 \frac{1-e^{-2\kappa \Delta t}}{2\kappa}
\end{aligned}
$$

Substituting the second equation into the first and solving for $m$ gives $m = a / (1-b)$. Use the same substitution in the third equation and rearrange to get
$$
\sigma^2 = \frac{\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}(\zeta) \cdot 2 \kappa}{1 - b^2} \>,
$$
but, recall that the variance of the equilibrium distribution (by looking far into the future) for $X(t)$ is just $\sigma^2 / 2 \kappa$ and so this gives your result.

---

**Addendum**: If you're wondering how the expression
$$
\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}(\zeta) = \sigma^2 \frac{1-e^{-2\kappa \Delta t}}{2\kappa}
$$
was obtained, it is via the (remarkable and beautiful!) [Ito isometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ito_isometry) and the fact that an Ito integral is a zero-mean martingale; namely, in this instance,
$$
\mathbb{E}\Big(\sigma \int_{t_0}^{\,t_0 + \Delta t} e^{-\kappa(t_0+\Delta t - s)} \, \rd W(s)\Big)^2 = \sigma^2 \int_{t_0}^{\,t_0 + \Delta t} e^{-2 \kappa(t_0 +\Delta t - s)} \, \rd s
$$
where we note that the integrand has been squared on the right-hand side and we "get to replace" $\rd W(s)$ with $\rd s$, converting the problem into one of solving a standard Riemann integral.

Comment: Oh I just got confused with the substitution as I got caught up with how did they set $\kappa=1$ to get that, which is not case at all and it is a simple substitution from previous equation. I did understand the derivation of variance of mean reverting process using ito-isometry. Thanks for a nice description.

Comment: @user862: I figured it might just be a simple situation like this. But, I thought the background of the question might be interesting enough to others that I'd put together a quick exposition. That way the question and answer are more self-contained, especially in case that link ever goes down.